# line regulation factor with 2 zener diodes

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, zener

i want to calculate the line regulation factor  of this circuit

[image]

You can check below my work.

is it right or not  ?

[image]

Correct me if  i'm wrong

Can we consider that  Z1  has  a similar function  as the zener diode in the picture below ?

[image]

Comment: Still breaking your teeth on this circuit? In my opinion, you make things hard on yourself because you're including **everything**. For example: depending on input and output voltages, Z1 does something or it does not. So then **simplify things** by assuming Z1 isn't doing anything so we can leave it out. Realize that you can later analyze again **with** Z1 doing something, you will get **two answers** 1) Z1 not present 2) Z1 present. But that's OK as the circuit **will behave differently for both cases**.

Comment: When Z1 isn't present: R1 and R can be combined. Next simplification: R1 + R + Z generate a reference voltage. Simplify by removing R1, R and Z and putting a **voltage source** in the place of Z. Next simplification, assume that the \$\beta\$ of the transistors is very large so no base current flows. *You but then my answer is incorrect* **True** but it might be **close enough**. It is always much simpler to start simple and then get a solution, then analyze again but taking more into account.

Comment: It would be **very optimistic** to assume that someone is going to check your equations (you would be very lucky) because experienced engineers don't work like this as it takes too much time. Experienced engineers **simplify** to get a "ballpark" number. Then we use a **circuit simulator** to get the real number (which should be close to the ballpark number or if not, we can explain why the simplified analysis was not correct).

Comment: I'm very grateful for your comments.
They opened my eyes .

Comment: How to express with a  equation the Z1 zener diode  contribution in this regulation circuit.

Comment: Your line regulation analysis is a **small signal** analysis so you need to replace the Zener diode with its small signal equivalent. An ideal zener diode, when biased, will behave as a **DC voltage source** which becomes a **short** in a small signal model. A more realistic model of a Zener diode will have some **series resistance** so instead of a short you would use that series resistance in the small signal model.

Comment: Do realize that, as mentioned before, Z1 is only active in certain situations. My guess is that it Z1 will only conduct when the output is overloaded or shorted. **Then the line regulation doesn't matter** because that is not "normal operation".